# Racket: Creating a stream using a macro instead of a function

Tags: stream, macros, racket, thunk

I'm currently attempting to create a stream using a macro, as shown below:

```
(define-syntax create-stream
  (syntax-rules (using starting at with increment )
    [(create-stream name using f starting at i0 with increment delta)
     (letrec 
       ([name (lambda (f current delta) 
                      (cons current (lambda () (name (f (+ current delta) delta)))))])
       (lambda () (name f i0 delta)))
    ]))
```

What happens though is I get a compilation error later on when I try to pass it the following lambda function, which says "lambda: not an identifier, identifier with default, or keyword".

`(create-stream squares using (lambda (x) (* x x)) starting at  5 with increment 2)`

What I suspect is happening is that by attempting to use lambda in a macro, it's shadowing the actual lambda function in Racket. If this is true, I'm wondering in what way one can create a stream without using lambda, since as far as I can tell, there needs to be a function somewhere to create said stream.

Also this is a homework problem, so I do have to use a macro. My equivalent function for creating the stream would be:

```
(define create-stream
  (letrec ([name (lambda (f current delta) (cons current (lambda () (name (f (+ current delta) delta)))))])
    (lambda () (name f i0 delta))))
```

Comment: instead of stripping away the `define name` part, try keeping `(define name (lambda () (fn i0))` as is, adding `name` after it, and see what happens. but you really should post a new question with all this.

Answer (score 1):

> What I suspect is happening is that by attempting to use lambda in a macro, it's shadowing the actual lambda function in Racket

No, that's not correct.

The problem here is that you use `f` and `delta` in binding positions, in `(lambda (f current delta) ...)`. That means after `(create-stream squares using (lambda (x) (* x x)) starting at  5 with increment 2)` is expanded, you will get code like:

```
(lambda ((lambda (x) (* x x)) current 2) ...)
```

which is obviously a syntax error.

You can see this yourself by using the macro stepper in DrRacket.

The fix is to rename the identifiers to something else. E.g.,

```
(define-syntax create-stream
  (syntax-rules (using starting at with increment )
    [(create-stream name using f starting at i0 with increment delta)
     (letrec 
       ([name (lambda (f* current delta*) 
                      (cons current (lambda () (name (f* (+ current delta*) delta*)))))])
       (lambda () (name f i0 delta)))
    ]))
```

This will make your code start running, but there are still other several bugs in your code. Since this is your homework, I'll leave them to you.

Comment: Thanks, that was quite helpful. I'm stuck on a new bug, though, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, what's your understanding of the problem? What have you done?

Comment: Well, what I've done to solve it at present moment is to create a helper function that creates the stream, and then have my macro call it and assign it to the stream-name `(lambda () (f i0))`. From everything I know, macros should be able to do this directly, but I haven't been able to figure out how to wrap it directly in my macro yet `(define sname (lambda () (f i0))`.

Comment: @Chris please post new question with [mcve] please.

Comment: @Chris your edit to the question invalidates this answer. this is not the way how questions are supposed to be asked on SO. instead, you should revert this question to its previous state, and post new question with a link to this one for reference background.

Comment: Alright, I've removed the edit. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem essentially boils down to this (broken) code

```
(let ((x 0))
    (define y x))
```

This is not equivalent to `(define y 0)` - `y`'s definition is local to the let-binding.

The solution is to flip the definitions around and make the `letrec` local to the `define`:

```
(define name
    (letrec (... fn definition ...)
        (lambda () (fn i0))))
```